# What contacts do the numbers on this DPDT relay refer to?

Tags: relay, dpdt

I’m new to electronics, could someone please list the contacts that belong to each number. e.g. COM1, COM2, NO1 etc.[image]

It’s a Taiss/JTX-2C, MK2P-I DPDT Power Relay with Plug-in Terminal Socket Base, DC 12V Coil, 8 Pin 2NO 2NC (Quality Assurance for 1 Years) DC 12V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram shows contacts in their normal state, and the slanting line shows the common contact. So you should be able to see that the pinout is:

1. Coil
2. NO1
3. COM1
4. NC1
5. NC2
6. COM2
7. NO2
8. Coil

You can't be sure which set of contacts is no. 1 and which is no. 2 but it doesn't matter as they're interchangeable.